# How to align center sent email from excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I want to center-align an email I sent from excel range selection using VBA but I'm not sure where to put it in the code. Someone suggested me to just add a column to my range. Is there anyway I can put the code in VBA. Btw, I'm really new at this language (like just an hour ago). Here's my code, I got it from a microsoft page:

```
Sub Send_Range()

ActiveSheet.Range("D4:L23").Select
ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
  .Item.To = "ABZ@123.com"
  .Item.Subject = "REMINDER: HELLO TEST" & " " & Format(Now, "mmmm yyyy")
  .Item.Send
End With
End Sub
```

Finished Product:
[image]

Comment: With this method you can't do much, but if you integrate outlook directly, you can do a lot more to format the body. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff458119(v=office.11).aspx) as a start. You can also use `.HTMLBody` and HTML formatting for even more control.

Comment: As @ScottHoltzman already mentioned, I usually prefer to usage of an [online HTML editor](http://www.quackit.com/html/online-html-editor/) to create the email I want and then copy the HTML code over to VBA `.HTMLBody`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple version of what Scott is referring to would be

```
Sub test()

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

sEmail = "Please check your status on " & Activesheet.Range("A1").value
'ie..Range("A1").value has the formula "=today()"

With OutMail
        .to = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        '.FROM = ""
        .Subject = ""
        .htmlBody = "<p align=""center"">" & sEmail & "</p>"
        .Send
End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this, the thing is I wanted to use the excel selection because it has a formula in it. How should I incorporate it? Or should I just translate the formula to vbascript?

Comment: You can build up your string to include and display the text how you want.  In the updated example range("A1") has the formula for todays date.  the sEmail value then is passed to the htmlBody.  Hope this helps. :)

Comment: I actually did what you said. I'm still building the html file but it's working. Thank you very much! :)